# how to change carousel caption's width in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the caption of a carousel having the same width of the background image (which means as the browser). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite carousel-caption class.
Here's an example:

```
  .carousel-caption {
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100%;
        background-color:white;
        color:blue;
    }
```